# Solving a System of Simultaneous Equations

Tags: equation-solving

I have the command:

```
Solve[{Cos[η] == Sqrt[3/6], 
Sin[α] Cos[η] == Sqrt [1/6], 
Sin[α] Sin[η] == Sqrt [2/6]}, {η, α}]
```

I get the output

```
{}.
```

What's the issue?

Comment: There is no point at which all three contours intersect: `ContourPlot[{Cos[η] == Sqrt[3/6], Sin[α] Cos[η] == Sqrt[1/6], 
  Sin[α] Sin[η] == Sqrt[2/6]}, {η, -Pi, Pi}, {α, -Pi, 
  Pi}]`

Comment: but you also have 3 equations and 2 unknowns?

Answer (score 4):

As said by @Mr.Wizard, you don't have a solution because it is a overdetermined system of equations, i.e., there are more equations than unknowns. 
If you look at @Mr.Wizard 's plot,

[image]

it is possible to note that the three equations has no common intersection.
But if you elliminate one of the equations you can find two points of solution.

```
NSolve[{Sin[α] Cos[η] == Sqrt[1/6.], 
  Sin[α] Sin[η] == Sqrt[2/6.]}, {η, α}]
NSolve[{Cos[η] == Sqrt[3/6], 
  Sin[α] Sin[η] == Sqrt[2/6.]}, {η, α}]
NSolve[{Cos[η] == Sqrt[3/6], 
  Sin[α] Cos[η] == Sqrt[1/6.]}, {η, α}]

(*{{η -> -2.186276035465284`, α -> -0.7853981633974483`}, {\
η -> 0.9553166181245092`, α -> 0.7853981633974483`}}
{{η -> -0.7853981633974483`, α -> -0.9553166181245092`}, \
{η -> 0.7853981633974483`, α -> 0.9553166181245092`}}
{{η -> -0.7853981633974483`, α -> 
   0.6154797086703874`}, {η -> 0.7853981633974483`, α -> 
   0.6154797086703874`}}*)
```